# Read posts from a Facebook fans page

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

One of my apps has a page on Facebook. This app is a Windows Phone app.

I don't know if I can do the following:

I want to read all posts from Facebook page and show it in a ListBox inside Windows Phone app.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facebook SDK from WP7: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples

Here is an example of reading a post: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples

Comment: thanks for your answer. And, may I need some rights to read posts. I think I must need a Facebook user to read posts from a Fans page.